# Assembly -(LMC) I'm supposed to make a program that takes 2 inputs of number but outputs the larger number

Tags: assembly, little-man-computer

```
         INP
        STA NUM1
        INP
        STA NUM2

      
        SUB NUM1
        BRP NUM2SHOW
        LDA NUM1
        SUB NUM2
        BRP NUM1SHOW

#NUM1   > NUM2
NUM1SHOW LDA NUM1 
        OUT
        HLT
#NUM2   > NUM1
NUM2SHOW LDA NUM2
        OUT
        HLT
NUM1    DAT
NUM2    DAT
```

Here is the code block, just looking at it, it seems like it's correct but for some reason it does not show anything when I ran the code.

I'm expecting for it to show the larger number. I've been using 4 as the first number at 5 as the second number, though like I said, it does not show anything at all.

Comment: Can you step through this program's execution, to see what it is actually doing?

Comment: What happens if you remove the comments?

Comment: Which LMC-simulator are you using to run the program? I ran your code on [this LMC simulator](https://trincot.github.io/lmc.html?code=+++++++++INP%0A++++++++STA+NUM1%0A++++++++INP%0A++++++++STA+NUM2%0A%0A++++++%0A++++++++SUB+NUM1%0A++++++++BRP+NUM2SHOW%0A++++++++LDA+NUM1%0A++++++++SUB+NUM2%0A++++++++BRP+NUM1SHOW%0A%0A%23NUM1+++%3E+NUM2%0ANUM1SHOW+LDA+NUM1+%0A++++++++OUT%0A++++++++HLT%0A%23NUM2+++%3E+NUM1%0ANUM2SHOW+LDA+NUM2%0A++++++++OUT%0A++++++++HLT%0ANUM1++++DAT%0ANUM2++++DAT%0A%0A&action=1&input=4+5) and it output 5 for your example input. I guess it is a limitation of your LMC tool.

Comment: Why haven't you reacted to our comments?

Answer (score 1):

Your program works in several different simulators, so your problem is probably a misunderstanding in using the tooling.

There's at least 5 LMC simulators out there, mostly web-based / online.  I like https://blog.paulhankin.net/lmc/lmc.html for an LMC simulator as a simple and effective LMC simulator.

---

To critique your program, there's more logic than needed for this.

Your doing something like:

```
if x < y
    print y;
if x > y
    print x;
```

This test for x < y and then x > y is redundant.  We would normally write something like this using an if-then-else, which chooses to run the then-part or the else-part with a single condition test<sup>1</sup>:

```
if x < y
    print y;
else
    print x;
```

---

While relevant, the above doesn't fully capture the redundancy.  Let's switch to if-goto-label to see more:

```
    if x < y goto print_y;
    if x > y goto print_x;
print_x:
    print x;
    (halt)
print_y:
    print y;
    (halt)
```

Here you can see that the second if statement either does the `goto print_x` or doesn't.  But where does it go next when it doesn't run the goto in the then-part?  It goes to `print_x:` by default as the next statement.  So, that means the second test either does `goto print_x` or doesn't but either way still ends up executing `print_x:` as next statement after — so, that if statement doesn't do anything to inform the program.

---

<sup>1</sup>  To do an if-then-else in assembly we test a condition, and goto the else part if the condition isn't met.  The then-part will execute when the condition is met, and then then-part must, when completed, skip the else-part.  In other words, the control flow either executes the then-part or the else-part, but only one of them — the other one is skipped one way or the other.

```
if x > y
    print x;
else
    print y;
(halt) // stop here whether the then or the else executed
```

```
    if x < y goto else1;
    print x;
    goto endif1;  // if we get here, we ran the then-part, so skip over the else-part
else1:
    print y;
endif1:
    (halt)
```

Comment: Does `lda` set flags in LMC?  If not, it's redundant to even have 2 `out` instructions (or `print` statements in the pseudo).  The most compact version would be load / sub, then load one, `brp` to conditionally skip another load, then fall through into `out` / `halt`.  Like pseudocode `A = y;`  `if (x>y) A = x;` / `print A` where A is the accumulator, as a temporary variable.  Or there are other ways to accomplish just setting A before one `out`/`halt`, without the optimization technique of doing something between setting flags and reading them.

Comment: Oh right, LMC doesn't technically *have* flags, but it also doesn't have negative numbers, so `brp` supposedly branches on the accumulator being non-negative but only works right after `sub`. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer).  What a messy design decision!  So you'd need an if/else like construct to set the accumulator ahead of one `out` / `hlt` if you want to do it that way, and tail-duplication to have one branch and separate `out`/`hlt` paths is probably the easiest logic to follow.